# Exibir resultado de tabelas diferentes com dados similares - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Nunca fiz isso, preciso criar uma QUERY para o MYSQL exibir dados de duas tabelas, uma tabela do gênero masculino e outra do gênero feminino. Sei que o correto é criar um campo para diferenciar o gênero, mas o exemplo abaixo é apenas didático, pois o que preciso é para outra estrutura de dados, onde o exemplo retrata bem o que preciso fazer.

> tbl_masc |
>   | id (int(11))
>   | nome (varchar(50))
>   | sobrenome (varchar(50))
>   | idade (int(3))
>   | data_nasc (datetime())
>
> tbl_fem |
>   | id (int(11))
>   | nome (varchar(50))
>   | sobrenome (varchar(50))
>   | idade (int(3))
>   | data_nasc (datetime())

Sei relacionamento de tabelas do seguinte modo:

```
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT 
            a.*,b.*,
            (
            SELECT 
                `cor` 
            FROM 
                `cabelo` 
            WHERE 
                `id_cor` = a.`cor_cabelo` 
            LIMIT 
                1
            ) AS `cabelo` 
        FROM 
            `tbl1` a 
        LEFT JOIN 
            `tbl2` b 
        ON 
            b.`id` = b.`id_pai` 
        WHERE 
            a.`status` = 'A' 
        ORDER BY 
            a.`nome` 
                ASC 
        LIMIT 
            12
        ;";
?>
```

A intenção da query acima é para que saibam que sei montar query, realizar consultas e o que for preciso dentro da minha limitação, pois não estou pedindo ajuda com algo mastigado, é que realmente não sei como fazer. Preciso de um norte para isso!

Comment: Você quer criar um loop no PHP ou fazer uma query que busque os dados nas 2 tabelas? Não ficou clara a questão.

Comment: Desculpe, corrigi

Comment: Continuei sem entender... vc quer selecionar os dados de duas tabelas diferentes é isso? Dá pra fazer isso só com um select, sem precisar fazer loop nenhum... se vc colocar parte do seu código PHP, talvez fique mais claro...

Comment: Isso mesmo, QUERY SELECT para o MYSQL rs

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar dados de mais de uma tabela, é só usar um `SELECT` com múltiplas tabelas. Tecnicamente isso seria um `JOIN` mas sem nenhuma cláusula de comparação entre elas. Isso retornaria todos os registros das 2 tabelas de acordo com o `WHERE`.

No exemplo que você deu, a query para retornar todos os dados das 2 tabelas seria:

`SELECT * FROM tbl_masc, tbl_fem;`

Você pode então tratar os dados no PHP ou limitar na query com `WHERE`, `LIMIT`, etc.

Comment: Vou experimentar, é preciso usar aliás caso tenha de realizar subquery's né, pois tem algumas dependências de relacionamento com dados de segunda importância.

Comment: Se tiver alguma dependência aí muda a query, pq vc vai precisar fazer um JOIN, mais parecido com o que vc colocou na pergunta. Mas como no seu exemplo a seleção é de duas tabelas sem relação entre elas e apenas com colunas iguais, não precisa fazer o JOIN (ele é implícito, como se fosse `JOIN 1=1`)

Comment: Não deu, pois se existem dois campos com o mesmo nome, teria de criar um apelido para ele, e depois não seria recuperado no looping, pois precisaria reutilizar o mesmo valor da array para ambos, então não consegui sem ter de usar algumas condições.

Comment: Então o exemplo que vc deu está incompleto. Você precisa de um JOIN para selecionar os campos que são iguais nos dois. No seu exemplo seria como encontrar homens e mulheres com a mesma data de nascimento por exemplo?

Comment: Não fera, creio que não leu até o final depois do exemplo, o que fiz foi um exemplo de que não quero mastigado pois sei um pouco de sql, pois geralmente se faz uma pergunta aqui no geral se pensa que você quer mastigado, e não é precisa, é limitação mesmo.

Comment: Estou me referindo a tabela q vc deu de exemplo... enfim, sem maiores detalhes sobre as tabelas e a query fica difícil conseguir ajudar...